# Page need to be refreshed for getting data second time to get data in Javascript and ajax in table

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

When i am putting data for the first time in html text box and hitting (getInputValue  --- button function) , the data is getting displayed, but for the second time it is not displaying.

I need to refresh the page to get the data again.

Is there any possibility to change this behaviour,i dnt want to refresh the page or anything.

```
function getInputValue() {

var inputVal1 = document.getElementById("id").value; -taking input from html text box and button click
var inputVal2 = document.getElementById("name").value; -taking input from html text box and button click
var inputVal3 = document.getElementById("city").value; -taking input from html text box and button click


 $(document).ready(function () {
    var tr ;
    var grid=$("#tblPopulation").show();
    $.ajax({
     url: /1234567:8080/qweerttgg/xyz ,
     dataType: "json",
     async:false,
     cache: true,
     type: "Get",
     success: function (data) {
         tr=data;
         console.log(data);
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          
             tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].Id + "</td>";
             
             tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].city + "</td>";
             tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].name + "</td>";
            
         }

         $('#tblPopulation').append(tr);
         tblFormate();
     },
     
    
      
    });
```

});
}

Comment: Is your `$(document).ready()` function only called from `getInputValue()`?

Comment: The code within `$(document).ready(function () {})` is executed only once (on document ready). Which is why, it is not getting triggered again.

Comment: Thanks for the understanding. Can you please help a bit more to fix this problem, can you please tell me or let me know arrange the code  in a way that it works.